# How do I fix this memory leak in my resize array method?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've created a simple integer array class:

```
#ifndef INTARRAY_H
#define INTARRAY_H

class IntArray
{
public:
    // Constructors / Destructor
    IntArray();
    IntArray(int size);
    IntArray(const IntArray& rhs);
    ~IntArray();

    // Methods
    int size();
    void resize(int newSize);
    void print();

    //Operator Overloads
    IntArray& operator=(const IntArray& rhs);
    int& operator[](int i);

private:
    // Data Members
    int* mArray;
    int mSize;
};

#endif
```

Now the issue is in the resize() method.  How do I know this?  Because I don't have any issues with any object until I create an object and use the resize() method.  When I run through the debugger, Visual Studio tells me I have some kind of pointer error once it goes through the destructor for the object that uses the resize function, and that object only.  All other objects run through the destructor fine.  Also, when I'm in the debugger and I delve into what's going on in the resize method, when I delete mArray inside, it does some funky stuff.  The thing is, it displays on the screen exactly how it should, I just get an error message.  Anyways, this is what my resize() method is and I put in some comments to help you understand what I was thinking I was doing as I implemented the code:

**EDIT: Added whole class for people who were asking**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "IntArray.h"
using namespace std;

// Constructors / Destructor
IntArray::IntArray()
{
    mArray = 0;
    mSize = 0;
}

IntArray::IntArray(int size)
{
    mSize = size;
    if (mSize == 0)
        mArray = 0;
    else
        mArray = new int[mSize];
}

IntArray::IntArray(const IntArray& rhs)
{
    mArray = 0;
    *this = rhs;
}

IntArray::~IntArray()
{
    delete[] mArray;
    mArray = 0;
}

// Methods
int IntArray::size()
{
    return mSize;
}

void IntArray::resize(int size, int newSize)
{

    int* temp = new int[mSize];  //Create temp dynamic array to store the values

    for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++)  //Copy values from mArray into the temp array
    {
        temp[i] = mArray[i];
    }
    delete[] mArray; //Delete the old array
    mArray = 0;
    mArray = new int(newSize);  //Create a new array with the new size

    if (mSize <= newSize)  //Copy the values from the temp array into the new array
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++)
        {
            mArray[i] = temp[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
        {
            mArray[i] = temp[i];
        }
    }
    delete[] temp;  //Delete the temp array
}  //Doesn't work :(

void IntArray::print()
{
    //cout << 
}

// Operator Overloads
IntArray& IntArray::operator=(const IntArray& rhs)
{
    if (this == &rhs)
        return *this;

    delete[] mArray;

    mSize = rhs.mSize;

    mArray = new int[mSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++)
    {
        mArray[i] = rhs.mArray[i];
    }

    return *this;
}

int& IntArray::operator[](int i)
{
    return mArray[i];
}
```

Thanks for any help.
**EDIT2: Yes, I know a vector is the exact same thing that I'm doing.  That's not the point.  I'm simply trying to understand pointers and dynamic memory inside of classes better and this is an exercise out of a book that simply gave me the header file code and asked me to implement it.**

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: `mArray = new int(newSize)` might be wrong.

Comment: Why do you allocate a new array just to make a perfect copy and then throw the original away? Why not just use the original for whatever purpose you wanted the copy? (Why not just `temp = mArray; mArray = new int (newSize); ...`

Comment: Can we see the rest of the class? The issue could be, for example, in the copy constructor.

Comment: Are sure that it is not your copy constructor/assignment/move operator that is wrong? Can imagine that if deleting the arrays twice would create some problems.

Comment: Why implementing a custom IntArray and not just use vector<int> from the STL? I would recommend to use this, if STL can be used and performance does not have to fulfill real time specs.

Comment: The resize() in std::vector will definitely be more performant than this, so I'd argue that the OP clearly does not have any particular performance requirements.

Comment: Adding the whole class for you guys

Comment: I'm not using vector because I'm trying to understand pointers and dynamic memory inside of classes better.  Otherwise, a vector would obviously simplify this 100 fold.........

Comment: Also, this is from an exercise in a book.  The book simply gives me the header class and asks me to implement it.

Comment: `IntArray::size` should be `const`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz is that not what I did?  I created a temp array and put the values inside so that I could delete the old mArray so that I wouldn't create a memory leak.  I then copied the values from temp into a new mArray with a new size.

Comment: @Cush What purpose did the first step serve? It's like you copied a document and then shredded the original. Why bother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `resize` function doesn't set `mSize`, so later operations probably run into trouble.

Here's a better implementation

```
void IntArray::resize(int newSize)
{

    if (newSize == 0)
    {
        mSize = 0;
        delete[] mArray;
        mArray = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int *newArray = new int [newSize]:
        for (int i = 0; (i < newSize) && (i < mSize); ++i)
            newArray[i] = mArray [i];
        delete[] mArray;
        mArray = newArray;
        mSize = newSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually found this out and implemented it a couple minutes ago.  Then came here and you had edited your answer.  This is what I was looking for :).  Basically I wasn't setting msize like you were saying BUT I also needed to set the address location of mArray to the newArray instead of what I was doing and deleting the newArray.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
void IntArray::resize(int newSize)
{
    int* temp = new int[newSize];  //Create temp dynamic array to store the values
    memcpy(temp, mArray, sizeof(int)*(mSize > newSize ? newSize : mSize));
    delete[] mArray;
    mSize = newSize;
    mArray = temp;
}
```

But you can have memory leaks if there will be exceptions. Using vector is better.

Comment: That definitely works.  Only  issue I have with that is that I have no idea how it works xD.  The book has never gone over a memcpy function before.  I'll have to look it up but I'm sure once I look it up I'll be quite confused by the pointer you have to the sizeof function.  The sizeof function from what I remember, gives me the number of bytes, in your case an integer which is 4, a type has.  Or is it actually dereferencing what's in the parenthesis to the right and not a pointer to sizeof?

Comment: @Cush, you know that new Entity[] - will allocate one block of memory. There will be newSize of ints, so in bytes there will be sizeof(int) * newSize bytes.
So you allocate memory of size you need. Then you copy to allocated memory bytes from old memory. And then store allocated memory in your class.

Look at `memcpy` function, at `? :` operator. Everything wiill be clear for you.

Comment: Instead of memcpy you can use std::copy(...), maybe that will be cleaner.